# Create shortcut to Settings > Keyboard > Text Replacement

Tags: ios, automation, shortcuts-app

Is there any way to create an Icon/Shortcut on my Homescreen which will directly get me to: Settings > Keyboard > Text replacements?

Even with Shortcuts and so called automation I wasn‘t able to do this on my own.

PS: iOS 15.1

Comment: Is this about how to get such a shortcut or about why it doesn‘t seem to be possible?

Comment: Yes, I‘d like to know if this is possible.